# ErrorException Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm just trying to get all the data from my table name posts but an error occur it wont let me display the data on my index.blade.php

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('posts.index')->withPosts('$posts');

    }
```

and here's my index.blade.php

```
@foreach( $posts as $post )
            <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">

                            {{ $post->title }} -> this is the one i want to display

                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">

                            {{ $post->body }}

                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on September 24, 2014</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
            </div>

                <hr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: dd($posts) in your controller and see whats output?

Comment: and try to return as `return view('posts.index')->with(compact('posts'));`

Comment: @blue moon hey your code works thanks for helping me

Comment: @blue moon how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it as

```
return view('posts.index')->with(compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `with` like this:

```
return view('posts.index')->with('posts',$posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

not use single quote in $posts

```
return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
```

or try second way as

```
return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact` method

```
return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions were not working, try this.

I may think that you just missed this single line **"enctype="multipart/form-data"** in your form.

*See example below:*

```
<form action="{{ route('upload.files') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple>
</form>
```

Don't forget to click the arrow up. I hope I did help you :)